# Create windows Cursors at run-time in MFC

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

I would like to be able to edit the bitmap data for the cursor, so that I can overlay information onto the cursor.

I have an app where the user selects different tools from a menu or toolbar, and then uses these tools to draw into the current window.  I would like to overlay the tool in the corner of the cursor, so that the user can see which tool is currently selected.  Now, I could draw lots of different cursors, but with 20 different tools, and several different options for the base cursor style, that's a lot of cursors to draw.

I would like to load the base cursor, and the toolbar image, combine them in code, and then use SetCursor() to use this cursor.  However, the windows API doesn't seem to have much scope for working with cursors, and CreateCursor() only seems to be able to create black and white images.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648062(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Just like icons, a cursor consists of 2 images: A monochrome mask and color information. Both images are combined using bitwise AND, to enable cursor transparency. See [ICONINFO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648052.aspx) (also used for cursors) for more information. I would advice to draw lots of cursors instead. This enables an artist to work in parallel to developers, allows for easy localization, and gives you the visual result you need. Getting the mask image right using code is hard.